# Select a number of items from an ordered list with decreasing probability in Python

Tags: python, list, probability

I have an ordered list that I want to select items from but with a decreasing probability and for the steepeness of that probability to be able to be changed. I have been able to select the first n number of items easily in Python using:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 ... 46]

subset = list[0:3]
```

and a random sample from that list as:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 ... 46]

subset = random.sample(list, k =3)
```

But I'm not sure how to get different probabilities within that range i.e. a greater probability of selecting 1,2 or 3 than compared to 44, 45 and 46 with the probability continually decreasing. This would also be for different subset sizes such as 5, 7, 10 and 16. Any ideas would be appreciated. I want this to be done without replacement.

Comment: Can you be more specific about *how* you want the probabilities to vary? Should 45 be 1/45th as likely as 1? Should it be half as likely? The problem as specified right now is underdefined.

Comment: This can vary, I want to be able to change the relative probabilities so in the extreme case, 1/45th as likely would be okay, but in a less extreme case it could only be 1/2 as likely

Answer (score 2):

Numpy's random.choice supports picking samples with weights:

```
from numpy.random import choice

pop = range(1, 47)

weights = [1/(idx+1) for idx in range(len(pop))]
sw = sum(weights)
weights = [w/sw for w in weights] # weights need to sum to 1

k = 3

print(choice(pop, k, p=weights, replace=False))
```

You can change the specifics of probabilities by constructing `weights` list with a different function.

Comment: To even out the probabilities the denominator of the weights just has to be made bigger? i.e. instead of +1, + 10 or +100 would even out the probability of selecting items that are not as close?

Comment: `+1` was added mostly to avoid zero division error for 0-th index. But yes, increasing this value will make the probabilities closer to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite broad, so I have developed quite a broad solution. It's probably not optimal in terms of computation time or storage space, but it does solve the stated problem and it is useful as learning device to understand how such an algorithm might work:

```
import random as r

def vectorTotal(vec):
    output = 0
    for x in vec:
        output += x
    return(output)

def reduce(vec):
    output = []
    for x in vec:
        output.append(x/vectorTotal(vec))
    return(output)

xValues = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
pValues = [10,6,8,1,8,2,3,9,1,20]

probabilities = reduce(pValues)

def pickWithProb(options, probs):
    rand1 = r.uniform(0,1)
    threshold = 0
    for i in range(len(options)):
        threshold += probs[i]
        if threshold > rand1:
            return(options[i])
    
    
pickWithProb(xValues, probabilities)
```

So the thing I called "xValues" are the options, I just put in 1:10 so it was easy to keep track of everything. "pValues" is the relative likelihood of each option being chosen, but it doesn't have to be a valid probability distribution. "Reduce" turns pValues into a valid probability distribution and "vectorTotal" was used to implement "Reduce".

In order to actually use this, it may be helpful to have some kind of function to actually generate pValues, something like:

```
def generatePValues(xValues):
    output = []
    for x in xValues:
        output.append(2**-x)
    return(output)
```

Comment: `vectorTotal` is the same as built-in `sum`

Comment: I agree that it is, but I included it to make sum more transparent in case OP isn't familiar with it. It can also be conveniently modified- if OP wanted something to find a vector's magnitude instead of its total, it's easy to modify the function to do that.

Answer (score -1):

This will work but it depends on your desired distribution I guess.

```py
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 ... 46]

def get_random_weighted_value(list):
    # Make this value lower to decrease the chance of each value being picked
    probability_value = 0.5
    for value in list:
        if random.random() < probability_value/value:
            return value
        # You can also add values to the probability value here
        # this will make the probabilities closer together
        # i.e.
        probability_value = 0.5 + (0.3*value)
```

This will select a value based on the following probabilities (for `probability_value = 0.5`):

`1: 50%, 2: 25%, 3: 16.75%`...

Comment: First of all, percentages you listed are misleading. This is a percentage change **assuming nothing before was picked**. So in fact it's `1: 50%, 2: 12.5%, 3: 2.09375%...` and quickly spinning off into negligible chances. That leads to the second problem, namely there is a fair chance that NONE of them will be picked, resulting in `None` return value - 1000 executions gave astounding 83 `None` results.

Comment: * slight correction, it's 6.28125 for 3.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. The percentages in the original answer are the threshold for each calculation and are based on independent events. You are correct with regards to the distribution being non-optimal - as I suggested in the code, modifying the `probability_value` to create a more even distribution is advisable, as required by OP the `the steepeness of that probability to be able to be changed`.

Comment: More even distribution would cause even **more** `None` values.

Comment: I have changed a single line of code to affect the distribution to make it more even (smaller jumps between independent probabilities). Additionally, if you are worried about the None values returning you can simply make the function recursive by adding a final line `return get_random_weighted_value(list)` which will force a non-null return value.